# Django: Is it possible to download a csv file from another website and add it to FileField through Django shell?

Tags: django

While using Django, when I need to do something on data from DB, I've always been using Django shell. For this time, I want to do something like the below scenario in Django shell.

I have a model Store with a bunch of stores. In Django shell,
1. import Store model
2. With each of store name, I search each name and download a csv file based on each store name.
3. Add the downloaded csv file to a FileField in Store model.

I know how to #1 and #3, but I'm confused how I can do #2. How can I input the store name and download a csv file from the store name in Django shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `requests` library to fetch data from the internet. Install it like this:

```
pip install requests
```

Then, in Django, you can use `ContentFile` to save the downloaded data into a FileField. Here's an example:

```py
import requests
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from .models import SomeModel

response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wireservice/csvkit/master/examples/test_geo.csv')

s = SomeModal.objects.get(id=0)
s.file_field.save('data.csv', ContentFile(response.content))
s.save()
```

Comment: The website that I download csv files from requires me logging in and I need to click a button to download. Can it be done with requests?

Comment: Probably, but it depends on the website. Try to find out if they have a public API you can send requests to, and how you might structure those requests. If it's a large website, they might even have their own Python client you can use.